# Sharepoint 2013 audit Discard check out

Tags: check-out, auditing

Is there a way to view an audit of when users have done the 'Discard Check Out' option for a library item?

We are looking at the audit reporting from Site Settings, and 'Check In' will show in the report, but if I click 'Discard Check Out' that doesn't come back in the audit report.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is done on purpose.  The reasoning behind it, is you do not want anything that you made to be saved.  SharePoint reverts to the previous version and ignores any updates made to the item.

The only thing I can think of is for you to write an Event Receiver that fires on ItemUncheckingOut.  This should trap the user who performed that step and when they did it.  Your code would look something like this (shooting from the hip)

```
public override void ItemUncheckingOut(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
       string userName = properties.UserDisplayName;
       string userLoginID = properties.UserLoginName;
       ...
       //Do something with this information
}
```

To the best of my knowledge there isn't anything out of the box that tracks this for you, so using that snippet I gave you might be your only option.

Hope it helps